# There is any shortcut method to add all values from the input document Id list to default dictionary as key and set value to 0

Tags: python, dictionary

**Following is my code description:**

1. There are two tables in DB, Document and Document Revision. Document Revision have Foreign Key of a Document table. One document have Multiple Document Revisions object.
2. Input to my function is Document Ids, and I want Count of Document Revisions against Document.[Working]

Suppose Input document Id's list is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and Only two documents I have Document Revisions rows in database. So I get document revision count for Document Id `2` as `11` and `4` as `43`. My script give output like `{2:11, 4:43}`

**Question:
 There is any short-cut method to add all values from the input document Id list to default dictionary as key  and set value to `0`**

Other way is by `for loop`

```
revsion_count = {}
for id in document_ids:
    revsion_count[id] = 0
```

**I am using Python 2.6**

**Code:**

```
def getRevisionsCount(self, document_ids):
    """Return Document Revision Count for Document.
       Input: Document_ids list.
       output: Dictionary with key is Document ID and Value is counter
    """
    import collections
    revsion_count = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for i in DocumentRevision.objects.filter(doc__id__in=document_ids).values_list("doc__id"):
        revsion_count[i[0]] = revsion_count[i[0]] + 1 
    return dict(revsion_count)
```

**Updated code according to lucas:**

```
def getRevisionsCount(self, document_ids):
    """Return Document Revision Count for Document.
       Input: Document_ids list.
       output: Dictionary with key is Document ID and Value is counter
    """
    revision_count = dict.fromkeys(document_ids, 0)

    for doc_id in DocumentRevision.objects.filter(doc__id__in=document_ids).values_list("doc__id", flat=True):
        doc_id = str(doc_id)
        revision_count[doc_id] = revision_count[doc_id] + 1 

    return revision_count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
revision_count = dict.fromkeys(document_ids, 0)
```

That will user keys from `document_ids` and each on with value `0`. Using your example, it will output something like: `{1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0}`.

Out of your question maybe it will be nice to use `flat=True` in `values_list()` so that it don't return a list of tuples since you are only using one field. In Example:

```
for i in DocumentRevision.objects.filter(doc__id__in=document_ids).values_list("doc__id", flat=True):
    revsion_count[i] = revsion_count[i] + 1
```

So that you don't need to use `i[0]`.